# Install4j: how to check a RemoteCallable running unelevated

Tags: java, singleton, install4j

My installer is storing some information in a singleton class during the installation process. Now, I have noticed that in elevated action, the singleton class does not have the same instance. So far, I have not found any workaround/solution so that they share the same instance. So, I have decided to make sure that if anyone wants to get an instance of the singleton, they must call from an unelevated environment. Let's say the singleton looks like the following:

```
public class InvestigatorReport {

    private final List<Report> reports = new ArrayList<>();
    private final static InvestigatorReport INSTANCE = new InvestigatorReport();

    private InvestigatorReport() {
        MyLogger.logInfo(getClass(), "initiating...");
    }

    public static InvestigatorReport getInstance(Context context) {
        if (context.hasBeenElevated()) {
            throw new IllegalAccessError(
                    "this method must be called unelevated!");
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private boolean addReport(Report report) {
        return reports.add(report);
    }
 }
```

But the problem is, There are some cases when I have to call this add report from an action class that is elevated. So I have tried the following in my elevated action class:

```
if (context.hasBeenElevated()) {
            return (Boolean) context.runUnelevated(new RemoteCallable() {
                @Override
                public Serializable execute() {
                    return getInstance(context).addReport(report);
                }
            });
        }
```

But, as you can see if I am passing the same context object from the elevated action class to the  `RemoteCallable` class so, even though I am running the class unelevated, the `context.hasBeenElevated()` still returns true.

Is there any other way that I can check the elevation level other than the context? If you have any other better idea on preventing anyone from calling the singleton `getInstance()` method, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different pattern. Make all methods of your singleton static and wrap the data access with `runUnelevated` calls:

```
public static boolean addReport(Report report, Context context) {
    context.runUnelevated(new RemoteCallable() {
        @Override
        public Serializable execute() {
             InvestigatorReport.reports.add(report);
             return null;
        }
    });
}
```

In that way, you can call the methods from both elevated and unelevated code without having to check anything at the call site.